# Best way to re-render form values in a MEAN stack app in form validation

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

It is necessary to re-render user filled form values back to the user during form validation. In a typical MEAN stack app, I tried the following, but I satisfied with none of them:

(1) Submitting the form by Ajax, therefore no need to re-render form values because the form values are there as there were. But in this case it is difficult to display error messages and highlighting error fields.

(2) Store the form values in the session and get the values from the session to re-render them.

(3) Store the form values in cookies and use the cookies to re-fill the form.

Is there any other better approach?

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Submitting the form by Ajax, therefore no need to re-render form values because the form values are there as there were. But in this case it is difficult to display error messages and highlighting error fields.

I suggest you go back and re-evaluate this option. If you don't like this, MEAN stack is probably not the right stack for you. AngularJS is completely on the side of SPAs and AJAX form submission. Its validation and error message capabilities in its form subsystem are fairly robust and substantial. If you are struggling with them, dumping them for full-page load form POST requests is perhaps an indication you need to redouble your efforts to work in harmony with AngularJS or pick a different tech stack that you find more enjoyable.